# Nodejs: How to replace certain characters within an array with other characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, character, substring

Say I have an array like this:

```
['test\\test1\\test2\\myfile.html', 'test\\test1\\test2\\myfile2.html']
```

I just want to replace all of the "\ \" characters with "/" and store this into a new array so that the new array should look like this:

```
['test/test1/test2/myfile.html', 'test/test1/test2/myfile2.html']
```

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of Array's to create a new Array

```
var replaced = ['test\\test1\\test2\\myfile.html', 'test\\test1\\test2\\myfile2.html'].map(function(v) {
  return v.replace(/\\/g, '/');
});

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned node.js, you can just use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var replaced = ['test\\test1\\test2\\myfile.html', 'test\\test1\\test2\\myfile2.html'].map(function (x) {
  return x.replace(/\\/g, '/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to traverse the array using any iteration method.

This will help you with that:

[For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript)

I think you can use the replace function of the String object.

For more reference, please go to:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = ['test\\test1\\test2\\myfile.html', 'test\\test1\\test2\\myfile2.html'];
    for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
    test[i] = test[i].replace(/\\/g,'/');
}
console.log(test);
```

outputs ["test/test1/test2/myfile.html", "test/test1/test2/myfile2.html"]